# Select radio button using Selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

```
<input type="radio" name="isLayoutApprov" value="Y"> 1.Approved &nbsp;&nbsp;
<input type="radio" name="isLayoutApprov" value="N">2.UnApproved
```

How we can write code for the above html in Python selenium?

Here type and name are the same, the only difference is value in this page another radio button with same values

Comment: Needs debugging details
The question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Need to see the entire page HTML or a link to the web page in order to create correct locators

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
driver.find_element_by_css("input[value='Y'][name='isLayoutApprov']").click()
```

to click on **Approved**

or

```
driver.find_element_by_css("input[value='N'][name='isLayoutApprov']").click()
```

to click on **UnApproved**

Comment: `in this page another radio button with same values`

Comment: but there could be a single radio button too, need OP comment on this. Anyway updated the code as well with css

Comment: Question is missing too much details

Comment: What do you mean ? that's python

Comment: change the name in css, I have used this css `input[value='Y'][name='isLayoutApprov']` did you try ? what was the error ?

Comment: @Prophet : See, we have this kind of users, who do not try instead they ask questions like is this in python ? :D similar elements already existed in the page. It's frustrating man they don't even try the solution that we provide .

Comment: I see. I try not to deal with such people. You will have to describe too much things and they still will not understand.

Comment: See his self answer. Medicine is powerless here.

Comment: @Prophet : Quote to live by